# Pixel Size Guidelines for Photoshop Designs for iOS Devices

Tags: ios, multiple-sizes

A designer asked me for guidelines on pixel sizes for their iPhone Photoshop screen designs.

I looked at the different sizes using [Paint Code App's Ultimate Guide to iPhone Screen Resolutions](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified). And I have suggested designing at 960x1704 [(320x568)*3], so that I can grab images at 3x resolution from the design and to make sure that width of everything will fit on iPhone that support iOS 8+.

Is this a good suggestion? Does someone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Hi Tobias, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!